# Display labels for marker Google Map API

Tags: c#, wpf, actionscript-3, flash

My WPF application uses the Flash API for google map. Everything works fine except that I need to show some custom details when the user clicks the balloons.

The actionscript code is below:

```
var map:Map = new Map(); 
map.key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
map.sensor = "true"; 
var marker : Marker; 
map.setSize(new Point(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight)); 
map.addEventListener(MapEvent.MAP_READY, onMapReady); 
this.addChild(map);  

var CustN:String;

function onMapReady(event:Event):void 
{   
    var centerLL : LatLng = new LatLng(38.05,-77.036562); 
    map.setCenter( centerLL, 10, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE); 
    map.addControl(new ZoomControl());
    map.addControl(new PositionControl()); 
    map.addControl(new MapTypeControl());   
    marker = new Marker( centerLL );  
    map.addOverlay( marker );   
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("Search",onSearch); 
}

function onSearch(lat:Number, lon:Number, CustName:String ):void 
{
    CustN  = CustName; 
    var centerLL : LatLng = new LatLng(lat,lon); 
    map.setCenter(centerLL, 10, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);   
    marker = new Marker( centerLL );  
    marker.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK, onMapClick); 
    map.addOverlay( marker ); 
}

function onMapClick(event:MapMouseEvent):void 
{  
    map.openInfoWindow(event.latLng, new InfoWindowOptions({title: "Click Event", content: CustN})); 
}
```

I call the onSearch function from my C# code as below:

```
 foreach (var rec in LstCoOrdinates)
        {
            XElement call = new XElement("invoke", new XAttribute("name", "Search"), new XAttribute("returntype", "xml"), new XElement("arguments", new XElement("number", rec.latitude)),
                new XElement("arguments", new XElement("number", rec.longitude)), new XElement("arguments", new XElement("string", rec.name)));
            axFlash.CallFunction(call.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
        }
```

I need to display the name corresponding to the balloon clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can specify DisplayObject .icon property in your g Marker. and change it's visibility on click.
Predefine label or set it on click whatever you need.

```
marker = new Marker( centerLL );  
marker.icon = new LabelSprite();
marker.icon.visible = false;
marker.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK, onMapClick); 
map.addOverlay( marker );

function onMapClick( e:Event ):void
{
  if(selectedMarker) 
     selectedMarker.icon.visible = false;

  selectedMarker = e.currentTarget as Marker;
  selectedMarker.icon.visible = true;
}


public class LabelSprite extends Sprite
{
  private var labelTextField:TextField;

  public function LabelSprite()
  {
    labelTextField = new TextField();
    addChild(labelTextField);
  }

  public function set labelText(value:String):void
  {
    labelTextField.text = value;
  }
}
```